# Property 'onChanged' is undefined on TextFormField extension

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield

I want to extend the `FormTextField` so that I can add a border and a hint but after creating the extension I get the following error:

```
: Error: The getter 'onChanged' isn't defined for the class 'TextFormField'.
text_field_extensions.dart:19
- 'TextFormField' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/text_form_field.dart' ('../../../Programming/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_form_field.dart').
text_form_field.dart:1
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'onChanged'.
            onChanged: onChanged,
```

And `TextFormField` contains `onChanged` property.

I've tried:

1. to restart the `Dart Analysis Server` but it didn't work.
2. `flutter clean` / `flutter pub get`

Extension code:

```dart
extension TextFormFieldExt on TextFormField {
  Widget outside(String text) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
            child: Text(
              text,
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
            ),
          ),
          TextFormField(
            initialValue: initialValue,
            onChanged: onChanged, # Error here
            keyboardType: keyboardType, # also on this one
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
              errorText: decoration?.errorText, # and this one
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I've got this error after changing `on TextField` to `on TextFormField`

Comment: Why do you need an extension for that? Please just use a widget and call it BorderTextFormField or something. Please edit your question accordingly. If the error isn't resolved by then, we'll find a solution.

Comment: I can create a widget for the border and I think I'll do that in the meantime but now I'm curious why it doesn't find the 'onChanged' getter

Comment: Also I didn't want to use a widget because I have to change the constructor for all the different properties that I want to add/remove. Extensions make this thing a bit easier

Comment: this is because `TextFormField` doesn't have it, check `text_form_field.dart` line #134

Comment: @pskink I've checked but on line #134 is this :`VoidCallback? onEditingComplete,` but on line #131 I have this: ` ValueChanged<String>? onChanged,`. I'm currently on Flutter 3.10.2

Comment: It's an argument in the constructor but it's not a property of `TextFormField` itself.
Check line 181 to see where it was used.

Comment: i meant flutter 3.12, on different versions it can be something else (but close to line #134 anyway)

Answer (score 1):

Simply because it doesn't have it, the `TextFormField` constructor is what let you pass that `onChanged` method as you can check if you do look into it's source code:

```
TextFormField(
 // ...
 int? maxLength,
 ValueChanged<String>? onChanged, // this.
 GestureTapCallback? onTap,
 //...
);
```

and then how it does uses it is that it is called inside another internal method that reach most deeper abstract widgets in Flutter:

```
   // ...
   void onChangedHandler(String value) {
         field.didChange(value);
         if (onChanged != null) {
           onChanged(value);
         }
       }
```

So actually there no memeber called `onChanged` in the `TextFormField` widget, and this is why you get an error when you try to use it in an extension method, as well as other properties.

That being said, you cannot use an extension method over it just like this, unless if you want to make another wrapper widget that takes an `onChanged` and passes it to the `TextFormField`'s onChanged, and then make an extension over it.

Comment: This actually sucks, I've tried on TextField and it has onChanged but it doesn't have initialValue which also doesn't help me. I've created a widget and removed the extension

Comment: This is just an opinion, using extension methods for in your own widgets code is not helpful, many things can happen with time of devlopment which will require refactoration, changes... and extension methods will make it harder, there is much packages that follow this approach such as `flutter_animate` since it can't be modified directly by it's user, but for an app, I recommend following Flutter widget tree approach and devide your widgets and resuse them as you want.